# How fuel gauge works?

Tags: fuel-system, fuel-tank

Can any one help me to understand the working theory for this fuel gauge. Is this similar to old type or does it has a digital sensor?

[image]

This sensor belongs to Man-vehicle, its labeled as man tx-d683. Sending unit has two wires. I want to know does it working as a variable resistor or in other way.

Comment: Different manufacturers use different systems; but essentially variable resisters on those I have seen.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: What is the vehicle in question (year/model/engine)? I understand it's a Man, assuming it's a diesel operated truck, but the rest of the information would be very helpful.

Comment: Most likely a simple variable resistor.  It may be on a lever arm, or it may be a kind of corkscrew implementation.

Comment: I want to read the sensor out put to Arduino board( using microcontroller). Do you have any idea to do this?